# Request response of HTTP 200 with error reporting in PHP ON, HTTP 500 with error reporting OFF

Tags: php, http, joomla

I have a Joomla! site page (/administrator/index.php?option=com_jcs) which shows my browser's 500 error page and a response code of HTTP 500 (Server Error) when 'Error Reporting' is switched to 'None' (off). However, when I switch error reporting ON ('Simple' or 'Maximum' in the Joomla! GUI) the response code switches to HTTP 200 response, but with a content-length of 0. The displayed page is blank.

I've tried setting error reporting using error_reporting() and ini_set() on index.php which results in the same behaviour.

I've recently upgraded PHP to version 5.3 on the server and fixed a couple of 'deprecation' notices (mainly ereg -> preg), however I can't think of anything else that would cause this. Any thoughts?

Comment: is `display_errors` set to 1 ?

Comment: I've just tried adding it to php.ini as well, without success. display_errors is 'on', but still a blank page.

Comment: try to disable error_reporting and check php and/or server error log file

Comment: Try turning on "Debug System" in Joomla backend.

Comment: I eventually reinstalled / upgraded Joomla and the component. Took a bit of time, but it worked :) Thanks for your suggestions.